# Crop video with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I try to crop a video in square with AVFoundation which I follow the tutorial from this web site http://www.netwalk.be/article/record-square-video-ios.

My question is how to crop a square video with an area that I selected (like when you select a photo in UIImagePicker or like in instagram). The example gives me a square video but cropping from the center.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: please share with me a demo if you have achieved this. Would be of great help mate or help me with this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43451879/square-video-using-avfoundation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice in the `// rotate to portrait` portion of the code they're making affine transformations.  Modify those transformations to align the video how you want.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have changed the affine transformations to make it works.